# How to execute js function on website using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to fill a form out (text boxes) using Excel VBA. The first problem is that the form is not recognising the values.

I tried using the below code but, same problem,  it still didn't work the form throws up a custom validation 'required' error

```
Set inputBox = document.getElementById("company_name")
inputBox.Focus
inputBox.FireEvent ("onchange")
inputBox.Value = somevalue.Value
```

Inspecting the html, I see that there is a custom `onchange` function

```
<input name="company_name" tabIndex="1" id="company_name" spellcheck="false"  onselect="ControlSelect(this, event);" onfocus="ControlFocus(this, event);" onblur="ControlBlur(this, event);" onchange="ControlChange(this, event);" oncut="stdControlCut(this, event);" onpaste="stdControlPaste(this, event);" type="text" size="68" maxLength="40" value="company" autocomplete="off" control_owner="PAGE" program_id="CEN100" screen_id="sid0007" page_name="main" control_owner_id="main" defaultvalue="" extendedchars="false" wildcards="false" securitytype="" security="COM_NAME" spellchecker="false" referential="" datatype="" changecase="" paste="true" server_change_enabled="true" valid="undefined" hasChanged="false">
```

how do I call `ControlChange(this, event);` from VBA?

I think that it involves the `eval` function buy not sure how to pass parameters to `ControlChange`

Answer (score 1):

you can use ExecScript method of the ("InternetExplorer.Application") object from vba, you can customize the javascript function variable to fire the event onchange with you desired value

```
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate "http://www.javascripter.net/faq/confirm.htm"
ie.Visible = True
While ie.Busy
DoEvents
Wend
ie.Document.ParentWindow.execScript code:="window.confirm = function(){return true;};"
ie.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")(0).Click
```

this code sets the window.confirm to true, this avoid the prompt that appears on the "onclick" method on the button from that document. (you can try clicking on that button to confirm that works)

anyway you can try too with your lines

```
inputBox.Focus
inputBox.Value = somevalue.Value
inputBox.FireEvent ("onchange")
```

first set the value on the input box, and then fire the event ("onchange"), i suggest to you  add a wait loop to wait the javascript function to complete.